# Активная вкладка браузера Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В моей программе у пользователя может быть открыто множество вкладок и мне надо понимать в какой он сейчас (активной) при условии что он сам переключается между ними. уже пробовал:

1. WinApi захват title активного окна, далее перебор по driver.WindowHandles - работает, но не красиво!! когда много вкладок открыто процесс занимает много времени и мешает пользователю работать, сам переключая вкладки.
2. брать хэндл через API, но он берет активного окна браузера а не вкладки

Answer (score 0):

Это использование селениума не по-назначению. Так что не стоит удивлятся тому, что там нету функционала отвечающего за работу с вкладками.

Подозреваю, что самым элегантным из решений будет разработка собственного плагина для браузера, который бы выдавал эту информацию твоей программе.

Все остальное будет костылями вроде захвата названий табов через WinAPI или запоминание какие вкладки открыты были в принципе (что не гарантирует актуальности информации)